# Docker Volume Data Replication Sync or Async

Tags: docker, docker-volume

To persist data of a docker container, volume is the solution.

But I wonder what the mechanism of this implementation is.

- Does docker help us to **replicate** container files to the host? If so, is it synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's different for named volumes vs. bind-mounted directories, and for bind mounts, it's different using the Docker engine directly on Linux or through a VM (maybe via the Docker Desktop application).  Do you have a specific code fragment where this behavior matters?

Comment: Hi, I did not write any code. Just learning the concept, I am confused about this point. @J_H

Comment: Thanks, I think I should know different kinds as you mentioned 
: 
"different for named volumes vs. bind-mounted directories, and for bind mounts, it's different using the Docker engine directly on Linux or through a VM (maybe via the Docker Desktop application)."

<br/>